# How to append json result from select box and distribute to div tag in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have code for filtering JSON data from select box to change a `div` value from HTML.

This is my code:

```js
window.onload = populateSelect();

function populateSelect() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/jqvlv',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(birds) {
      var xxx = document.getElementById('sel');
      for (var i = 0; i < birds.length; i++) {
        // POPULATE SELECT ELEMENT WITH JSON.
        xxx.innerHTML = xxx.innerHTML +
          '<option value="' + birds[i]['ID'] + '">' + birds[i]['Bird_Name'] + '</option>';
      }
    }
  });
}

function show(xxx) {
  // GET THE SELECTED VALUE FROM <select> ELEMENT AND SHOW IT.
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
  msg.innerHTML = 'Selected Bird: <b>' + xxx.options[xxx.selectedIndex].text + '</b> </br>' +
    'ID: <b>' + xxx.value + '</b>';


  var vv = document.getElementById('vv');
  vv.innerHTML = 'ID: <b>' + xxx.value + '</b>';
}
```

```css
select,
p,
input {
  font: 1em Calibri;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bind SELECT Element with JSON using JavaScript</title>
</head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <!--The SELECT element.-->
  <select id="sel" onchange="show(this)">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  </select>

  <div id="msg" </div>
    <br />
    <div id="vv" </div>

</body>

</html>
```

How to make my other `div` get specific value from JSON data? Example for data harga, my code is running with returned same value.

Comment: What is the issue? I think you're code runs perfectly.

Comment: hi, thank you for help me, my problem is i dont know how to parse data Harga from json value to my specific div

Comment: What's your JSON sent from the server?

Comment: no, my json is from online json,  https://api.myjson.com/bins/jqvlv

Comment: You're making an `ajax` call and getting a parsed object from the call in `birds` which you're using to set `div.innerHTML`, still unable to figure your issue

Answer (score 0):

You can persist JSON data with `<OPTION>` element. Create option using jQuery i.e. `$('<option>')` create element construct and the use various DOM method to set value i.e. `.val()` and text i.e. `.text()`.

Using `.data()` method you can save arbitrary data with element which can be retrieved later.

```js
window.onload = populateSelect();

function populateSelect() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/jqvlv',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(birds) {
      var xxx = $('#sel');
      for (var i = 0; i < birds.length; i++) {

        //Create option using jQuery create element construct and use various DOM method to set value and text
        var opt = $('<option>');
        opt.text(birds[i]['Bird_Name']);
        opt.val(birds[i]['ID']);
        opt.data('json', birds[i]);
        opt.appendTo(xxx);
      }
    }
  });
}

function show(xxx) {

  var data = $(xxx).find('option:selected').data('json');
  console.log(data.Harga);
  console.log(data);
  
  $('#msg').html('Selected Bird: <b>' + JSON.stringify(data));

  $('#vv').html('ID: <b>' + $(xxx).val() + '</b>');
}
```

```css
select,
p,
input {
  font: 1em Calibri;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="sel" onchange="show(this)">
  <option value="">-- Select --</option>
</select>
<div id="msg"></div>
<br>
<div id="vv"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should remove 'onchange' event in your select tag and use this code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#sel').change(function(){

        var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
        msg.innerHTML = 'Selected Bird: ' + $("#sel option:selected").text(); + ' ' +
            'ID: ' + $("#sel option:selected").val() + '';


        var vv = document.getElementById('vv');
        vv.innerHTML = 'ID: ' + $("#sel option:selected").val(); + '';
        });

    });
```

You can try this one it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want yo display all data in different `divs`, please consider the following:

```js
window.onload = populateSelect();

function populateSelect() {
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/jqvlv',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(birds) {
      var xxx = document.getElementById('sel');
      for (var i = 0; i < birds.length; i++) {
        show({
          id: birds[i]['ID'],
          name: birds[i]['Bird_Name']
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

function show(xxx) {
  var msg = document.getElementById('msg');
  msg.innerHTML += 'Bird: <b>' + xxx.name + '</b> </br>' + 'ID: <b>' + xxx.id + '</b><br /><br />';
  var vv = document.getElementById('vv');
}
```

```css
select,
p,
input {
  font: 1em Calibri;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bind SELECT Element with JSON using JavaScript</title>
</head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="msg"> </div>
  <br />

</body>

</html>
```